# Jquery dropdown menu on hover or on click

Tags: jquery, click, hover, drop-down-menu, children

I have a menu which looks like the one below. I want the first-level childs to appear on hover OR on click (so it works on iPad as well). When hovering (or clicking) a firs-level child I want it's second level childs to appear if they exist. On hover out or when clicked on a different DOM-element all submenu's should be hidden again.

Also when a user is on page I want to menu to be folded out until he hovers over or clicks on a different menu item so he can always see just where he is in the navigation.

I am building this in Wordpress for a friend who should be able to create and change his navigation menu using the backend. Therefore adding specific classes or ID's to some elements is not an option.

```
<style>
.sub-menu {display: none;}
</style>


<ul class="menu">
  <li>child 1
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li>child 1.1
        <ul class="sub-menu">
          <li>child 1.1.1</li>
          <li>child 1.1.2</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>child 1.2
        <ul class="sub-menu">
          <li>child 1.2.1</li>
          <li>child 1.2.2</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>child 2
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li>child 2.1</li>
      <li>child 2.2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

This is what I came up with but it does not work. When hovering over child 1.1 both 1.1 and 1.2's siblings are shown.

```
$("ul.menu li").hover(function() { 
    $(this).find("ul.sub-menu").not("ul.sub-menu li ul.sub-menu").slideDown(); 
} , function() {  
    $(this).find("ul.sub-menu").hide(); 
});

$("ul.menu li ul.sub-menu").hover(function() { 
    $(this).find("ul.sub-menu").slideDown(); 
} , function() { 
    $(this).find("ul.sub-menu").hide(); 
});
```

Comment: just a comment, ipad will make the hover action into a click action, if your primary option in your menu dosen't redirect anywhere it will display your menu, so if your menu is going to work that way don't bother making both actions (hover and click)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following solutions by Directly targeting the `ul`

***Solution A***:

---

```js
//  previous (following) is very inefficient and slow:
//   -- $(this).find("ul.sub-menu").not("ul.sub-menu li ul.sub-menu").slideDown(); 
//  Rather, target the exact ULs which are Direct Children

$("ul.menu").find('li').hover(
    function() {
        $(this).find('> ul').slideDown();
    },
    function() {
        $(this).find('> ul').slideUp();
        //  If something Slides Down, it should slide up as well,
        //  instead of plain hide(), your choice - :)
    }
);
```

***Solution B***:

---

for more Precision over both ULs

**Update**: Solution A works fine and makes B redundant

```
$("ul.menu").find('> li').hover(
    function() {
        $(this).find('> ul').slideDown();
    },
    function() {
        $(this).find('> ul').hide();
    }
);

$("ul.sub-menu").find('> li').hover(
    function() {
        $(this).find('> ul').slideDown();
    },
    function() {
        $(this).find('> ul').hide();
    }
);
```

Check the **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/OMS_/XDkXq/)**

Answer (score 0):

This is untested .. and you have to expand it a bit.

```
$('ul.menu li').siblings('ul:first-child').on('click', function() {
if($(this).is(':visible')) {
    $(this).hide();
}
else {
    $(this).show(); 
}
})

$('ul.menu li').siblings('ul:first-child').hover(
function() {
    $(this).show();
},
function() {
    $(this).hide();
}
)
```

Edit: As I see your structure is inconsistent. Sometimes you place a list IN a li element, sometimes it is placed as a sibling...

Comment: Use $(this).toggle() on click instead of show/hide and a condition.